# SQL Trigger for Average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding trigger.

Let's say I have two tables, one called **'studentData'** and the other **'studentStanding'**.

> 'studentData' is a table consist of teacherID, studentID and rating.
>   So different teacher may give different rating to a single student

(ex: teacherID: 1 gives rating: 5 to studentID: 3 AND teacherID: 7 gives rating: 10 to studentID: 3)

> studentStanding is table consist of studentID, studentName and averageRating.

My intention is to create a TRIGGER;

Every time a new teacher  (example teacherID: 120) gives rating to studentID: 3, 
this TRIGGER will recalculate the average Rating of this student 3.

I had tried to write the trigger but I'm pretty sure it is completely wrong. 
Here's how it looks:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAVG
AFTER INSERT ON studentData
REFERENCING NEW AS N_ROW
   FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE studentStanding SET Rating = (
      Select AVG(Rating) 
      from studentData
      )
```

I'm looking forward to anybody who could help me. Feel free to put suggestions on my trigger too. Thank you.

Note: This is NOT a school assignment, I promise!

Comment: Will an `UPDATE` of `studentData` ever take place or will it always be an `INSERT`?

Comment: I just realized a problem: `studentData` uses an ID but `studentStanding` uses a name.  How can we join these tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi, sorry I forgot to add studentID in the `studentStanding`

Comment: Have you considered making studentStanding into a view that calculates the average rating for each student?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER computeAvg
AFTER INSERT ON studentData
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE studentStanding
    SET averageRating = (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM studentData
                         WHERE studentStanding.studentID = studentData.studentID)
    WHERE studentID = NEW.studentID;
```

Comment: Hai, thank you for the input. By the way, the last statement `WHERE studentID = NEW.studentID` is referencing to which studentID? studentData?

Comment: It is referring to the `studentID` in the `studentStanding` table.  This `WHERE` condition means only updates records which were just affected by the `INSERT`.  Without this, the trigger would peform an `UPDATE` on the entire table (not logically wrong, but very inefficient).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.

Comment: This approach does have a couple of penalties associated with it.  `1.` Each time a new rating is added, all previous ratings *(per student)* have to be read and averaged.  `2.` If multiple ratings are added simultaneously *(for the same StudentID)* then the averageRating will be recalculated multiple times redundantly.  An alternative approach could be to maintain two columns `totalRatingsCount` and `totalRatingsSum`, these can be maintained without rejoining to the `studentData` table, and then the average can be a calculated field as `totalRatingsSum / totalRatingsCount`.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the insights.  I could argue the other way by saying that a computed column has a higher overhead due to storage space, but I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you for your inputs :)